# Speed up numpy indexing of large array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array `x` of size `(n, n, p)` and I need to index it using a list `m`. I need to return a two new arrays of sizes `(n, m, p)` and `(n, n-m, p)`. Both `p` and `m` are generally small (range 10 to 100), but `n` can be from 100 to 10000+.

When `n` is small, there is no issue. However when `n` gets large, these indexing operations take the majority of my function call time.

In my actual implementation, the indexing took 15 seconds, and the rest of the function was less than 1 sec.

I've tried doing the regular indexing, using `np.delete`, and `np.take`, and `np.take` was faster by a factor of 2 and it was what I am currently using to get the 15 sec time.

An example is below:

```
m = [1, 7, 12, 40]
r = np.arange(5000)
r = np.delete(r, m, axis=0)

x = np.random.rand(5000,5000,10)

%timeit tmp = x[:,m,:]
1.55 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit tmp2 = x[:,r,:]
1.7 s ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit tmp = np.delete(x, r, axis=1)
1.46 ms ± 31.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit tmp2 = np.delete(x, m, axis=1)
1.64 s ± 18.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit tmp = np.take(x, m, axis=1)
1.21 ms ± 61.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit tmp2 = np.take(x, r, axis=1)
1.04 s ± 79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Except instead of 1 sec, it's 15 times that and I have to call this function a few hundred or thousand times.

Is there something I can do to speed this indexing up?

I'm using Python 3.6.10 through Spyder 4.0.1 on a Windows 10 laptop with an Intel i7-8650U and 16GB of RAM. I checked the array sizes and my available RAM when executing the commands and did not hit the maximum usage at any point in the execution.

Comment: More or less these times are all proportional to the number of elements that have to be copied to the result,  5000/4 = 1250; 1700/1.5=1090.  You might see if `numba` is any faster.  `np.delete`, takes different strategies, depending the delete selection.  One is to construct a boolean array of `True`, and set the deletes to `False` - then index.

Comment: Can you provide hardware information such as your processor and your memory speed as well as the version of the Python interpreter? On my machine all these operations are much faster (between 5 and 10 times) and succeed to relatively efficiently use the hardware.

Comment: I've added the information in the post.